# Dimension reduction to subsystem in Pauli-Liouville basis: How to implement partial trace of Pauli-Transfer Matrices?

Tags: quantum-operation, pauli-gates, pauli-group

I have a complementary question to my previous (thankfully answered, but I can't verify for larger systems) question:

[Multi-qubit quantum channels in Pauli-Liouville basis: Tensor product of Pauli-Transfer Matrices?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/35432/multi-qubit-quantum-channels-in-pauli-liouville-basis-tensor-product-of-pauli-t)

How can we represent the partial trace operation, to project into the lower dimension of the subystem, in Pauli-Liouville representation (aka Pauli-Transfer Matrices)? And, how can we code it up (say in Python)?

Let's say we have the $n$ qubit Pauli-Liouville basis set given as $B_{PL} = \left\{I/\sqrt{2}, X/\sqrt{2},Y/\sqrt{2},Z/\sqrt{2} \right\}^{\otimes n}$. Also, let's say we use a standard quaternary convention (base 4 numbers) to enumerate these bases. e.g., For a 2 qubit system of parties $A$ and $B$ the first basis $P_0^{AB}=0.5I^A\otimes I^B$, can be denoted as $\tilde{P}_0^A = \tilde{P}_0^B I/\sqrt{2}$. Similarly the second basis $P_1^{AB}=0.5I^A\otimes X^B$, can be denoted as $\tilde{P}_0^A = I/\sqrt{2}$, and $\tilde{P}_0^B X/\sqrt{2}$, and so on. In this PL basis we expand our density matrix in this complete, orthonormal basis set by projecting via Hilbert-Schmidt norm, $\langle{A}|B\rangle{} = \text{Tr}\left[A^{\dagger}B\right]$, such that expansion looks like the following.

$$
\rho = \sum_i c_i P_i \;\;\; \rightarrow \;\;\; c_i = \text{Tr}\left[\rho P_i\right]
$$

Because of this summation notation, we can vectorize our density operator in real numbers as $||\rho\rangle\rangle_i = c_i$. Here $c_i \in \mathcal{R}^{2n \times 1}$. For example, a single qubit ground state $\rho_{GS}=|0\rangle\langle{0}|=(1/\sqrt{2})I/\sqrt{2} + (1/\sqrt{2})Z/\sqrt{2}$ such that the PL vectorized form is the column vector $||\rho\rangle\rangle_{GS} = [1/\sqrt{2},0,0,1/\sqrt{2}]^T$. Since (partial)trace is a linear operation, we could apply to each constituent Pauli-string term $P_i$ in the sum.

$$
\rho_B = \text{Tr}_B\left(\rho\right) = \sum_i c_i \text{Tr}_A\left(P_i\right)
$$

For the two-qubit case, we can dig deeper to get an intuition. As expressed in the answer to my previous question, if we denote the (quaternary notation) Pauli-string index with a double-index (for each qubit) as $i = i_1 i_2$. such that $i=0 \leftarrow i_1=0,\; i_2 =0$, $i=1\leftarrow 01$ and so on, we can write each Pauli-string term as $P_i^{AB} = P_{i_1}\otimes P_{i_2}$. In this case, we can write the sum above as the following as the partial trace turns to a normal trace for the $A$ subsystem Pauli-strings because this is the partial-trace of a tensor-product.

$$
\rho_B = \sum_{i_1i_2}c_{i_1i_2}\text{Tr}\left(P_{i_1}\right)P_{i_2}=\sqrt{2}\sum_{i_1=0,i_2}c_{i_1i_2}P_{i_2} = \sqrt{2}\sum_{i < 4 }c_i P_i
$$

Here the trace operation "killed" (zeroed) $P_{i_1}$ elements that are not identity (i.e., $i_1 \neq 0$ in the standard quaternary notation) because the trace of each Pauli matrix is zero, $0=\text{Tr}\left(P_{i_1}\right)|_{i_1 \neq 0}$, and the $\sqrt{2}$ on the front is coming from $\sqrt{2}=\text{Tr}\left(P_{i_1}\right)|_{i_1 =0}=\text{Tr}\left(I\right)/\sqrt{2} $. This means that when we trace out the qubit $A$ only the first four elements related to the partial-trace of the elements with indices $i=0 \leftarrow 00$, $i=1 \leftarrow 01$, $i=2 \leftarrow 02$, $i=3 \leftarrow 03$ survive with an extra multiplicative factor $\sqrt{2}$. Similarly, tracing out the subsystem B should also correspond to reducing the vector in $PL$ basis with respect to the demarcation points in Pauli-string enumeration convention, and multiplying with a factor.
$$
\rho_A = \sqrt{2}\sum_{i_1,i_2=0}c_{i_1i_2}P_{i_1i_2}=\sqrt{2}\sum_{i \in 
\text{Demarcation}=[0,4,8,12]} c_i P_i
$$

For example, the density operator for two uncorrelated qubits that were initialized in the ground state is given as $\rho_{AB}=\rho_{GS}^{A}\otimes\rho_{GS}^B = |0\rangle_A\langle{0}_A|\otimes |0\rangle_B\langle{0}_B|$. The combined system and its partial-traces verifies this fact.

$$
||\rho\rangle\rangle^{AB} = ||\rho\rangle\rangle_{GS}\otimes||\rho\rangle\rangle_{GS}  \ =[1/\sqrt{2},0,0,1/\sqrt{2}]^T\otimes[1/\sqrt{2},0,0,1/\sqrt{2}]^T \
=[1/2,0,0,1/2,0,\dots,0,1/2,0,0,1/2]^T

And, going back to the original state, the Pauli-Liouville version of the partial-trace I defined above verifies this,

$$
||\rho\rangle\rangle_i^{A}=||\rho\rangle\rangle_i^{B}=\sqrt{2}c_{i<4}=\sqrt{2}c_{i \in 
\text{Demarcation}=[0,4,8,12]} = [1/\sqrt{2},0,0,1/\sqrt{2}]^T
$$

Can we say that tracing out multiple subsystems, such as $BCD$ in $ABCD$ to get $A$, also amounts to identifying the correct demarcation points in the Pauli-string enumeration convention and the correct multiplicative factor? Can we generalize this?

$$
\rho_A = 2^{3/2}\sum_{i_1i_2i_3i_4\in \text{Demarcation}}c_{i_1i_2i_3i_4}P_{i_4} 
$$

PS: Again $i_4 \in \text{Demarcation}$ denotes the standard quaternary notation (base 4) indices $i_1i_2i_3i_4$ where the last digit $i_4 = 0$.